# Jest TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'html') at new JSDOMEnvironment

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, monorepo

I've setup a monorepo with Node.js and React.

Trying to configure jest to run test suites the api Node works fine but I got the following error on the client side:

```
 FAIL client/src/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'html')

      at new JSDOMEnvironment (../node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:72:44)
```

This is root jest.config.ts:

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
  roots: ['<rootDir>/server/src/tests', '<rootDir>/client/src/'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testMatch: ['**/src/**/*.test.ts', '**/src/**/*.test.tsx'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/client/src/setupTests.ts'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['(test/.*.mock).(jsx?|tsx?)$'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  verbose: true,
  projects: [
    '<rootDir>/server/jest.config.ts',
    '<rootDir>/client/jest.config.ts',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage/',
};

export default config;
```

The client jest.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  displayName: 'client',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};

export default config;
```

And the script that fires jest in package.json scripts:

```
 "test:ci": "jest",
```

It seems that is not running react testing library.

However if I run the client test directly like so it works:

```
"test:client": "yarn workspace @mern-monorepo/client test",
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Seriously wishing that this had a valid answer! I'll come back and put one if I can figure it out.

Comment: Hey Brad I could make it work ! Thanks for your kind reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after digging quite a bit I finally got the solution.

This are the steps to follow:

1. yarn workspace @mern-monorepo/client add --dev jest-environment-jsdom
2. yarn workspace @mern-monorepo/client add --dev identity-obj-proxy

Then I added to the client jest.config.ts file:

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  displayName: 'client',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['\\.(css|scss|sass)$'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts'],
};

export default config;
```